# Coupling Hypergeometric(N,k;n) and Bin($n,\frac{k}{N}$)

Tags: probability

I am stuck with the following two questions (b) and (c) showing a coupling of hypergeometric(N,k;n) and Binomial($n,\frac kN$).

In it $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim HG(N,k;n)$ with $X_i=1(\text{the i-th draw is red})$, if we consider the model as drawing $n$ times without replacment out of a box of $N$ balls with $k$ red balls. We know that $X_i\sim Ber(\frac kN)$, although they are dependent. Similarly we want $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\sim Bin(n,\frac kN)$ with $Y_i$ being i.i.d. $Ber(\frac kN)$.

[image]

So my questions are:

**For question (b)**, it is easy to show this construction provides $Y_i\sim Ber(\frac kN)$. But I don't know how to show they are independent. I have tried computing $$\mathbb{P}(Y_i=\sigma_i,\cdots,Y_n=\sigma_n\mid Y_1=\sigma_1,\cdots,Y_{i-1}=\sigma_{i-1}),\mathbb{P}(Y_1=\sigma_1,\cdots,Y_n=\sigma_n\mid X_1,\cdots, X_n),$$

but for the first quantity I don't know how to calculate the conditional probability, and for the second I get $$1(X_1=\sigma_1)\prod_{i=2}^n[(1-\frac{i-1}{N})1(X_i=\sigma_i)+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{m\leq i-1}1(X_m=\sigma_i)]$$ and then I need to take expectations over $X_i$'s, which I don't know how to simplify the product terms.

**For question (c)**, I don't get the hint, i.e. how to randomize the ordering and why this will help. My confusion is that $X$ is the sum of these $X_i$'s, thus $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\mid\sum_{i=1}^n X_i]$ is computed given the sum of these $X_i$'s instead of their individual values. How do we ensure $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]=X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We construct a model for this coupling, which immediately shows that $Y_i\sim Ber(\frac{k}{N})$.

We consider two urns with black balls and white balls respectively. The first urn has $N$ black balls with $k$ labelled $1$ and the rest labelled $0$, while the second urn has $N$ white balls without any other differences. We choose at random from the second urn, and if the drawn ball is white, we draw at random from the first urn a black ball, put it in the second urn, and record the number on the ball. If the drawn ball from the second urn is black, we record the number on it and replace it.

Now we let $X_i$ be the number on the $i$-th black ball drawn from the first urn, $Y_i$ be the number on the ball drawn by our scheme after we have drawn the $(i-1)$-th black ball from the first urn. Clearly we have $X_i$'s are those dependent $Ber(\frac KN)$ r.v.s for hypergeometric distribution. Also, $Y_i$ is exactly the same as defined in the context of problem $(b)$, for $Y_i=X_i$ if the $i$-th drawn from the second urn is white, which has probability $1-\frac{i-1}{N}$, and $Y_i=X_m$ if the drawn ball from the second urn is exactly the ball with number $X_m$. From the construction of the scheme it is easy to see that $Y_i$'s are i.i.d. $Ber(\frac kN)$ since each time it is equivalent to sample with replacement from an urn of $N$ black balls with $k$ 1's and $(N-k)$ 0's.

We prove this coupling is the desired one. Now fix $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\ell$ for some $\ell$. Then we have some $(X_1,\cdots, X_n)$ with the desired sum. The scheme is equivalent to first draw $n$ black balls out of the first urn, then sample $n$ white balls out of the second urn, and finally pair them up. Since these $X_i$'s are exchangeable, it is equally possible for each $Y_j$ to be paired with each $X_i$, which implies the expected value of $Y_j$ given $X=\ell$ is

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_j\mid X=\ell]=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{n}=\frac{\ell}{n}.$$

Summing them up we get $$\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=\ell]=\ell,$$

yielding the desired identity.